# set all fonts except for one class to certain font

Tags: css, fonts, bootstrap-4

I want to use the font-family `Quicksand` throughout my whole website, except for the elements which have been assigned to the class `.font-arvo`, those should be in the font-family `Arvo`. I am trying to achieve this with the following css:

```
*:not(.font-arvo) {
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

.font-arvo {
    font-family: "Arvo", "google", serif;
}
```

However, this sets all elements, including those with the class `.font-arvo`, to `Quicksand`. If I do only the following, the elements with class `.font-arvo` are, as expected, in the correct font-family, but then the others are not:

```
.font-arvo {
    font-family: "Arvo", "google", serif;
}
```

**Note 1:** I do have included these fonts correctly in the `<head>` section.

**Note 2:** I am using Bootstrap 4.

Is there anyone who knows a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just be able to apply the base font to the `body` element and then overwrite any specific sections with the `font-arvo` class like so:

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

.font-arvo {
    font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo|Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
<h2>Here is the default font</h2>
<h2 class="font-arvo">And here is the second</h2>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [CSS Specifity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

MDN defines it as

> which CSS property values are the most relevant to an element and,
>   therefore, will be applied

Use the * selector for the default of all other elements

MDN defines it as

> The * selector selects all elements.
>   The * selector can also select all elements inside another element

For example, in your case, write

```
.font-arvo {
 font-family: "Arvo";
}

* {
 font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add needed font-family to `html, body {}` class?

Comment: Elaboate, please.